# Postfix: allow unlisted sender only for a specific IP/Application

Tags: postfix, odoo

To avoid backscatter emails, on Postfix I set:

***smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = true***

But this prevents the Odoo from sending some particular emails, since it uses some custom aliases as sender:

`SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'myuser@mydomain.com': (550, b'5.1.0 <bounce+92-account.invoice-40@@mydomain.com>: Sender address rejected: @mydomain.com')}`

How can I whitelist the Odoo server/app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making this a global directive, place `reject_unlisted_sender` in `smtpd_sender_restrictions` (it must appear after `permit_mynetworks` and `permit_sasl_authenticated`, if you used that).

Now you can add the sender's IP address to `mynetworks =`  to whitelist it and cause it to bypass this check.

An example from my live mail server:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_unlisted_sender,
        reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
        permit
```

Comment: I spent a lot on this ... Thank you so much.

Comment: Trying to tuning the solution I discovered that I have to set this sequence: _permit_mynetworks_, _reject_unlisted_sender_, _permit_sasl_authenticated_ 
otherwise, if _permit_sasl_authenticated_ precedes the other rules, I can send e-mails without adding the IP of the Odoo server to _mynetworks_.

Comment: Well that's a policy decision you can make. I have authenticated users able to send email from any address.